# Graphcool-framework cli on local: "Unknown flag –schema"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphcool

I was following a video tutorial on GraphQL and React.

The tutorial initializes `graphcool-framework` using this command:

```
graphcool-framework init --schema https://graphqlbin.com/hn-starter.graphql --name Hackernews
```

When I executed this command, I got this error:

```
Unknown flag --schema
```

Comment: FYI: "It’s so hard to say goodbye! Graphcool will be sunsetted July 1, 2020. " from their website :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the new version of graphcool-framework doesn't have the flag `--schema` if you want to follow the video-tutorials you better install the old version(that is the version they are using in the videos).
To install the version you need of graphcool-framework do:

`sudo npm install -g graphcool@0.4`